# Change name of generated war file and duplicate war file

Tags: gradle

i want to set the filename of the war task output before it is deployed to repository.
e.g. project name is `abc` and originally it would result in 
abc-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war

But i want that there should be two generated war files with the same content:

- `def-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war`
- `ghi-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war`

Comment: Isn't it as simple as to `copy` the war file as another file after the build process?

Comment: I think that's possible but there should be a more elegant way to rename the output file. Further the original war file should not deployed to repository.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
task doPack(type: War, dependsOn: []) {
    archiveName "ROOT.war"
```

That worked for me

Answer (score 34):

In build.gradle you can set the archive name:

```
war.archiveName "YOUR_SPECIAL_NAME.war"
```

[gradle reference](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War%3aarchiveName)

Comment: i am using this but it always generates the war file in lowercase letters(for example `root.war`) but i want it to be in uppercase(for example `ROOT.war`), how can i achieve this?

Comment: @Ramswaroop Works fine for me. Maybe you are building on a non case sensitive file system like in Windows?

Comment: @Sebi Nope, I was building on mac.

Comment: @RamPatra Mac is by default case insensitive

Answer (score 8):

Another one, for example:

```
war {
    baseName = 'service'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-' + System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For gradle version 5 and above, they have deprecated properties 'baseName' and 'archiveName'.

So you can use 'archivesBaseName' instead.

```
war {
    archivesBaseName = 'name'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more solution:

```
war {
    baseName = 'name'
    archiveName = "${baseName}.${extension}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Gradle7 and looking forward to easily upgrade to version 8 use something like this:

```
war.archiveFileName = '[your_name].war'
```